# mySql innoDB write queries locked for long time by read queries

Tags: mysql, innodb, table-locking

I have a mySql innoDB database with a table (with auto increment primary key). I have many processes performing a read operation on the table. I have other (few) processes that need to write in the same table within a time interval (less than 30 seconds). The write processes sometimes experience a timeout cause they find the table locked (for more than 30 seconds) by the read operations.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior and allow the write processes to write even if other processes are reading?

Answer (score 0):

The main cure for such is to speed up the reads.  Let's see some of them, together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Often it is as simple as adding a 'composite' index.

If this is a Data Warehouse application, and the reads are big "reports" that read lots of rows and do a `GROUP BY`, then an excellent solution is to [*build and maintain Summary Table(s)*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables).